# golang url.PathUnescape can not worked in %%

Tags: go, url

I use golang url.PathUnescape function to unescape url, but it can not worked in %%.

I receive a request it url is /search/?ptp=1&q=%27%22&%%3cacx%3e%3cscript%20%3emcyv9834%3c/script%3e&t=bao.
when I use golang url.PathUnescape function to unescape url, but it has error is invalid URL escape "%%3". Why?

```
package main
import (
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    str := `/search/?ptp=1&q=%27%22&%%3Cacx%3E%3CScRiPt%20%3EmCyV9834%3C/ScRiPt%3E&t=bao`
    a, b := url.PathUnescape(str)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

The origin url is /search/?ptp=1&q='"&%mCyV9834&t=bao .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it has error is invalid URL escape "%%3". Why?

Because %%3 is not a valid percent encoding in an URL path.

If you need to deal with malformed URLs you must implement that yourself. (Or fix upstream.)

Comment: Python url parse is right. Golang url lib can not parse %%%, so I write a function deal with this question.